# How do I tell what element has the focus on page load? Is this possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

I'm looking for some code that I can run in the `jQuery(document).ready()` function that will let me get the current focused element. Is this possible?

Cheers,
Pete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.activeElement) (also on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533065%28VS.85%29.aspx)), which is roughly the same thing. It will start out as the `<body>` element, unless the user or a script has moved the focus.